# C# - understanding Objects, Classes, and Method interactions

Tags: c#, class, object, methods

Very, very new programmer here facing some big troubles, I am trying to achieve as follows:

I want to write a very basic program in which the user is prompted to input two double variables, I then want the program to call separate methods, that will perform mathematical operations on those two variables and provide the user the answers.
Example of desired output:

**Input First Number**

x

**Input Second Number**

y

**Add: z**

**Subtract: z**

My aim in this is to practice using objects, but I am having issues, see this snippet as an example.

```
 class Variables
    {
        public string First { get; set; }

        public string Second { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
         Variables inputs = new Variables()
        {

                 Console.WriteLine("Please input first number"),
                 First = Console.ReadLine(),

                 Console.WriteLine("Please input second number"),
                 Second = Console.ReadLine(),
                 
        };



      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Addthem();

        }
        public string Addthem()
        {
            double answer = Convert.ToDouble(inputs.First) + Convert.ToDouble(inputs.Second);
            return ("Added: " + answer);
        }
    }
```

When trying to call Addthem, I have no 'object reference',

in my object 'inputs', I cannot print to console to prompt user input?

And finally (most mind bogglingly to me), my Main method is not suitable as an entry point for the program, this is what I am MOST clueless on.

Am I even on the right track? As I said very novice so sorry for egregious errors or general ignorance, I am just trying to better understand what I am not seeing in the interactions between Classes, Objects, Methods.

Comment: Were you able to write the same logic without using class and method? Did you get a chance to learn about class and methods from msdn and millions of other sources available on internet?

Comment: If you mean just in main yes I could produce logic similar to what I wanted, I have watched some videos and read some other posts online about them. I am just wanting to get better understanding from something I wrote after viewing some of those materials.

Comment: @user16369124 Your error is basically that you're reading a value from a null value. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes#example) is how class objects are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got all the ingredients right, but they need to be rearranged to make a good cake. Main() is the entry point, so anything you want to do has to be inside Main() or be called by something inside Main().

A useful concept to know is the difference between a class and an object.
A class is just a specification which says you can have these properties and methods, but you need to create an instance of the class first.
An object is an "instance" of a class and you can call the class methods (functions) through that object. Eg `inputs` is an instance of the `Variables` class.

```
    using System;
    
    class Variables
    {
        public string First { get; set; }
        public string Second { get; set; }
        
        public string AddthemInClass()
        {
            double answer = Convert.ToDouble(First) + Convert.ToDouble(Second);
            return ("Added: " + answer);
        }
        
    }
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // You had the code to initialise `inputs` outside of Main(), 
            // so it wouldn't get executed 
            // It needs to be inside Main()

            // `inputs` is created as an instance of the `Variables` class
            Variables inputs = new Variables();
            Console.WriteLine("Please input first number");
            inputs.First = Console.ReadLine();
    
            Console.WriteLine("Please input second number");
            inputs.Second = Console.ReadLine();
    
            // You need to tell Addthem() what to work on, ie, pass in `inputs`
            var result = Addthem(inputs);
            Console.WriteLine( result );
            
            // Or, you could call AddthemInClass through the `inputs` object 
            // because AddthemInClass is a method of Variables class
            var result2 = inputs.AddthemInClass();
            Console.WriteLine( result2 );
        }
        
        // This should be a static method. If you don't do this, you need to have it 
        // in a class and call it through an instance of that class
        // You could put it inside Variables class - see AddThemInClass()
        public static string Addthem(Variables inputs)
        {
            double answer = Convert.ToDouble(inputs.First) + Convert.ToDouble(inputs.Second);
            return ("Added: " + answer);
        }

}
```